# Returned JSON properties are not string in my node.js express app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

For my node.js express app, I'm using [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to request data over REST API.

This is my request implementation in **app.js**

```
var request = require('request')
request.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', {
  headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    consumer_key:'...',
    access_token:'...',
    contentType:'article',
    sort:'title'
  })
}, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body))
})
```

And I'm getting JSON response as the following

```
{ status: 1,
  complete: 1,
  list: 
   { '890245271': 
      { item_id: '890245271',
        resolved_id: '890245271',
        given_url: 'http://davidwalsh.name/open-graph-data-nodejs',
        given_title: 'Get Open Graph Data with Node.js',
        ... } 
   },
  error: null,
  search_meta: { search_type: 'normal' },
  since: 1444630917 }
```

The problem is that this is invalid JSON as JSON properties need to be string. What am I missing here?

Comment: That response you're showing in the second code block is what `console.log(JSON.parse(body))` logs?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm seeing in Terminal

Comment: Then your app is working just fine. You're parsing the JSON response in `body` to a JavaScript `object`, using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Thanks, I admit I followed someone else's code without breaking it down. Do you normally parse JSON before rending in view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *parsing* the JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body))
// Here ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So what you're seeing is the `console.log` representation of the JavaScript object resulting from parsing the JSON.

If you want to see the JSON instead, just don't parse:

```
console.log(body);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I don't know well enough about JSON after all. For a novice learner, would you mind sharing when to parse JSON and when not to?

Comment: @SeongLee: JSON is a *textual* notation, so when you're dealing with JSON in code, you're dealing with a string. If you want to write code dealing with the information in that JSON string, you parse it. So for instance, if you have the JSON string `'{"answer":42}'` and you want to know what the answer is, you parse the string (`var obj = JSON.parse(str);`) and then access the data (`obj.answer`).

Comment: @SeongLee: One thing that may be confusing you is the number of confused people out there saying "JSON" when they really mean "JavaScript object." You see this on SO all the time: "I have this json: `var obj = {answer: 42};` That isn't JSON, it's JavaScript code. But it's an extremely common mistake, and so could be confusing you if you've seen people doing that. The rule is simple: If you're writing code that's interacting with it, and it isn't *in a string*, it isn't JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's clear for me now.